# How to run a batch file with C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I need to run the batch file, wait for it to finish and end the process. The bat file starts another process that intensively prints data to the console, I need to redirect all the output to a certain method and not to show any windows.

I tried all the options, but every time the bat file process gets the Exited state before the internal process is finished, if I use waitforexit() then the process blocks and freezes when the output of the internal program is finished, please help
Bat file is correct, it worked with c++ previously.

here is one of the solutions I tried:

```
class Program
{
  static string batchFilePath = "example.bat";
  static void Main()
  {
    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFilePath);
    pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    using (Process process = new Process())
    { 
      process.StartInfo = pInfo;
      process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
      {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
        }
      };

      process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
      {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
        }
      };

      process.Start();
      process.BeginOutputReadLine();
      process.BeginErrorReadLine();

      process.WaitForExit();
    }
  }
}
```

Content of the Bat file:

```
db2cmd /i other.bat arg1 arg2 arg3
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit 1
```

Comment: Show what you tried, and show the values of any variables.  For an expert to spend 99% of an answer to tell you all the things you already know helps no one.

Comment: Exited event happens just after it starts

Comment: I need to run that bat file, because there are other programs that uses that bat file, so I just trying to keep compatibility

Comment: @AntonDanko, your question states that your batch file starts another process. A batch file is not needed/required to start a process. There is no need to be deliberately evasive, just show us the actual batch file content, and somebody may be able to improve your workflow, and at the same time solve your particular issue.

Comment: ^ I second Compo if just to make the attack vector smaller. Starting a bat is nothing I haven't done before but that system didn't have network connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I changed the bat file, the program works correctly.

I added "/c" to the db2cmd arguments:

```
db2cmd /i /c other.bat arg1 arg2 arg3
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# BATCH FILE
echo "OK"
echo "Very Ok"
echo "Awesome"
```

In order to run the batch file, the System.Diagnostics native C# library must be used. The batch file will be opened by CMD and the batch file path will be passed as a parameter to it.

```
static Process p = new Process();

string batch_file_path = "C:\\Users\\Teodor Mihail\\Desktop\\test.bat";

p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"; // <-- EXECUTABLE NAME
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // <-- REDIRECT THE STDOUT OF THE SCRIPT FROM SCRIPT TO OS, TO SCRIPT TO C# APPLICATION
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k \"" + batch_file_path + "\""; // <-- COMMAND TO BE RUN BY CMD '/k', and the content of the command "PATH" 
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // <-- CREATE NO WINDOW
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // <-- USE THE C# APPLICATION AS THE SHELL THROUGH WHICH THE PROCESS IS EXECUTED, NOT THE OS ITSELF
p.Start(); // <-- START THE APPLICATION


while(true)
{
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

    if (output.Contains("Awesome"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Awesome found");
        p.Kill();
        p.Dispose();
        break;
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

You can run a loop that listens for a certain input, then kill the process if found.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the System.Diagnostics.Process class's static Start method. Here's the simplified code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string batchFilePath = @"C:\Path\To\Your\BatchFile.bat";

        // Start the batch file
        Process.Start(batchFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to redirect output and get exit code also

Comment: Your solution is horrible, I'm not giving you a dislike, but.......

Comment: @teodormihail: That’s not very constructive. Can you clarify _why_ it is “horrible”? That will help others understand why they shouldn’t take this approach.